# ANSI background on only one space/ end the colour

Tags: python

I'm trying to change the background colour of a space (" ") to red using the ANSI escape sequence.

```
print('\u001b[41m')
```

This changes the background of the entire line to red. How can I make it stop after one space?

Comment: Send the reset sequence - `\u001b[0m`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [rich](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/stable/introduction.html) to simplify how to send the sequences

```py
from rich import print

print('[red reverse] [/red reverse]other text')
```